# RPi 5 Python Shhutdown command shutsdown then reboots

Tags: power, python-3, pi-5

The issue I am facing is that my RPi 5 running bookworm is running a heavily modified version of the script found on https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-safe-reboot-and-shutdown-button/all

It is the interrupt program version

```
# safe_restart_shutdown_interrupt_Pi.py
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#                 Raspberry Pi Safe Restart and Shutdown Python Script
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
# WRITTEN BY: Ho Yun "Bobby" Chan
# @ SparkFun Electronics
# MODIFIED: 3/18/2021
# DATE: 3/31/2020
#
#
# Based on code from the following blog and tutorials:
#
#    Kevin Godden
#    https://www.ridgesolutions.ie/index.php/2013/02/22/raspberry-pi-restart-shutdown-your-pi-from-python-code/
#
#    Pete Lewis
#    https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-stand-alone-programmer#resources-and-going-further
#
#    Shawn Hymel
#    https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/python-programming-tutorial-getting-started-with-the-raspberry-pi/experiment-1-digital-input-and-output
#
#    Ben Croston raspberry-gpio-python module
#    https://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs/
#
# ==================== DESCRIPTION ====================
#
# This python script takes advantage of the Qwiic pHat v2.0's
# built-in general purpose button to safely reboot/shutdown you Pi:
#
#    1.) If you press the button momentarily, the Pi will reboot.
#    2.) Holding down the button for about 3 seconds the Pi will shutdown.
#
# This example also takes advantage of interrupts so that it uses a negligible
# amount of CPU. This is more efficient since it isn't taking up all of the Pi's
# processing power.
#
# ========== TUTORIAL ==========
#  For more information on running this script on startup,
#  check out the associated tutorial to adjust your "rc.local" file:
#
#        https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/raspberry-pi-safe-reboot-and-shutdown-button
#
# ========== PRODUCTS THAT USE THIS CODE ==========
#
#   Feel like supporting our work? Buy a board from SparkFun!
#
#        Qwiic pHAT v2.0
#        https://www.sparkfun.com/products/15945
#
#   You can also use any button but you would need to wire it up
#   instead of stacking the pHAT on your Pi.
#
# LICENSE: This code is released under the MIT License (http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT)
#
# Distributed as-is; no warranty is given
#
# -----------------------------------------------------------------------------

'''
setup

sudo nano /etc/rc.local
sudo python /home/sox/Documents/Sox/safe_restart_shutdown_interrupt_Pi.py &
'''


import time
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO #Python Package Reference: https://pypi.org/project/RPi.GPIO/

# Pin definition
reset_shutdown_pin = 5
light_pin = 4

rebootSec = 2
shutdownSec = 4
scanRate = 0.25

# Suppress warnings
GPIO.setwarnings(False)

# Use "GPIO" pin numbering
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

# Use built-in internal pullup resistor so the pin is not floating
# if using a momentary push button without a resistor.
GPIO.setup(reset_shutdown_pin, GPIO.IN, pull_up_down=GPIO.PUD_UP)
GPIO.setup(light_pin, GPIO.OUT)

# Use Qwiic pHAT's pullup resistor so that the pin is not floating
#GPIO.setup(reset_shutdown_pin, GPIO.IN)

# modular function to restart Pi
def restart():
    print("restarting Pi")
    command = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -r now"
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
    

# modular function to shutdown Pi
def shut_down():
    print("shutting down")
    #GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.LOW)
    command = "/usr/bin/sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now"
    import subprocess
    process = subprocess.Popen(command.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = process.communicate()[0]
    print(output)
    

GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.HIGH)


while True:
    #short delay, otherwise this code will take up a lot of the Pi's processing power
    time.sleep(0.5)

    # wait for a button press with switch debounce on the falling edge so that this script
    # is not taking up too many resources in order to shutdown/reboot the Pi safely
    channel = GPIO.wait_for_edge(reset_shutdown_pin, GPIO.FALLING, bouncetime=200)

    if channel is None:
        print('Timeout occurred')
    else:
        print('Edge detected on channel', channel)

        # For troubleshooting, uncomment this line to output button status on command line
        print('GPIO state is = ', GPIO.input(reset_shutdown_pin))
        counter = 0

        while GPIO.input(reset_shutdown_pin) == False:
            # For troubleshooting, uncomment this line to view the counter. If it reaches a value above 4, we will restart.
            #print(counter)
            counter += 1
            time.sleep(scanRate)

            if counter*scanRate > shutdownSec:
                if counter % 4:
                    GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
                else:
                    GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.LOW)

            elif counter*scanRate > rebootSec:
                if counter %2:
                    GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.HIGH)
                else:
                    GPIO.output(light_pin, GPIO.LOW)

        # long button press
        if counter*scanRate > shutdownSec:
            shut_down()

        #if short button press, restart!
        if counter*scanRate >rebootSec:
            restart()
```

This code runs perfectly fine, pressing button results in a reboot, press and hold flashes the led in the button, then shuts it down, status light on RPi 5 turns red.

And then it turns green again. And comes back to full life, VNC works again levels of life. Shutting down via the logout button on the desktop does work though

Due to this, I am fairly certain it is a setting outside of my code, but I am unsure of how to even trace this error.

Thank you for reading

Comment: Why do you want to use any code (particularly old code using obsolete methods) when the Pi already has a power button? The Pi5 hardware is vastly different. Even on older Pi you don't need ANY code to implement a shutdown button.

Comment: what is your specific question?  ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post

Comment: How do I make a power button work for a button that is not the mini button that now exists on the Pi 5? Both shut down and reboot from on, and boot from off  @jsotola

Comment: @Milliways To implement a shutdown and reboot button similar to large computers without having to rip the Pi's button off and replace it.

Comment: If you checked the documentation you will find that there is already provision for an [external power button](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#add-your-own-power-button) which can be connected to a header on the Pi5.

Answer (score 0):

This "code" imports RPi.GPIO which does NOT work on a Pi5.

It MAY actually run (I haven't tried on a Pi5) but it certainly won't be able to access any GPIO because the Pi5 uses a different SoC.

Comment: I have swapped the code from RPi.GPIO to the twin which uses the same package name, but supports Pi5. https://pypi.org/project/rpi-lgpio/

Comment: In other words you decided to waste peoples time by posting code which doesn't work.

Comment: NOTE lgpio is NOT a twin it is a totally different library with different commands. If you want to use it install the supported python3-lgpio from the repository.

Comment: which is what I did. This code should work but does not. I guess this stack exchange haI did install the other one. My error still occurs. I thought the entire point of this site was to ask for help, not just showboat code

Comment: If you want help you NEED to post the code you actually use including diagnostics. The code you posted will not work, but if (as you stated in Comments) you want "to implement a shutdown and reboot button similar to large computers without having to rip the Pi's button off and replace it" you don't need ANY code - just attach the button to the appropriate header.